# An easy path to roam files in C#

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I have some text files in my project and I want their content to be available in the PC and Phone version with the same Microsoft Account.

Here is a screenshot of what I mean:
[My text files in the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlXeb.png)

The Content of the files are less than 100KBs and I believe I can use roaming, but I don't have any idea of how to do that.
Can somebody help me please?

Comment: I've used  OneDrive api to upload and download text files, but I thought that wasn't a proper way to do. So I searched and found roaming codes, but now I  don't have any idea how to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the **Application data sample** which is part of a [huge set of API samples for Windows 10](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples) on GitHub.

https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/ApplicationData